# Upload files to the server from iOS app

Tags: ios, file-upload, upload

Can I upload files other than images to the server on iOS app? I use    UIImagePickerController, which allows to pick image or take a photo, then I attach them and  upload to the server. Can I do the same thing with word or pdf files in my iPhone
Please, help me!

Comment: What server? And `UIImagePickerController` doesn't let you attach anything. It is for picking an image or taking a photo. You need to clarify this question.

Comment: I believe you can. Dropbox certainly can sync PDF, ZIP and other types of files so I would say yes you can. Maybe converting the file to NSData and sending the data to the server with a networking library like AFNetworking (note: I haven't tried it myself).

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for ASIHTTP Library use here [ASIHTTP Library Download](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Url"];

[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value1"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value2"];

[request setTimeOutSeconds:20];

//Create a 256KB file
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:256*1024];
NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

[request setFile:path forKey:@"file"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Suppose are you using PHP Server that side following code may be help to you

```
$filedir = '';
$uploadfile = $filedir.basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);


move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

Comment: I don't understand, this code uploads file existing in my iPhone, right? But how to give opportunity to user to choose which exact file should be uploaded?